# UFW open range is still blocked

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables

I have opened up a range of ports using UFW. The rules in question are shown below (output of `sudo ufw status numbered`). I have restarted UFW since I added the rule, yet in `lnav` I still see log entries showing up that the incoming connection is being blocked.

I have very little knowledge about `iptables` (hence using `ufw`) so I'm not sure how to debug this problem.

**Log Entry**

```
[2211067.364323] [UFW BLOCK] IN=p5p1 OUT= MAC=<mac> SRC=<ip> DST=192.168.1.130 LEN=40 TOS=0x18 PREC=0x20 TTL=54 ID=5307 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=20022 DPT=6889 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

**ufw output**

```
[16] 6881:6891/tcp              ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[29] 6881:6891/tcp (v6)         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

**iptables entry**

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 6881:6891
```

The [output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10736180/) of `iptables -L` for good measure.

Comment: I played with ufw a year or so ago as, like you, I struggled with iptables. Im no expert but I managed to figure it out. However I pretty quickly installed the gui, GUFW. Are you able to run the gui or are you desktopless ? You might find you have made a subtle misconfiguration that the GUI will fix for you.

Comment: It's my server, so yes it is headless.

Comment: Allow incoming on port 20022, want to see what happens.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/122157/debugger-for-iptables) already?